# Log-in screen not coming after deleting non-root partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on HP Zbook. This is not dualboot, there is no Windows here. System ran well for 2 days.

Yesterday I deleted one of the unused partition using GParted(without unmounting it). Probably because of that machine is NOT able to reach the Log-in Screen. I get GRUB menu. There I choose Ubuntu. Then I get purple screen for ever. I do not get log-in screen.

Here is the GRUB output. I have 3 physical disks on my laptop. Two SATA and one mSATA.

```
GRUB> Ls
(hd0) (hd0, gpt3) (hd0, gpt2) (hd0, gpt1) (hd1, gpt1) 
**(hd2) error: failure to read sector**
```

**Questions**

a) Hd2 is not a root partition and so I expect the OS to at least boot. Assume Hd2 had failed because of **real failure**; in that case how to make the OS boot.

b)  Does this happen to both *Internal* and *External* hard disks?
Assume I shutdown the machine without unmounting an External hard drive. Will the machine refuse to boot the next time?

**Solution attempted**

I  physically removed the hd2 from my laptop. That did not help at all.

Is there a way to resolve this problem without reinstalling OS?

Thanks (assume that I barely know anything about Linux ecosystem)

Comment: Have you tried to boot with a live USB and then run [**boot-repair**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Yes I tried booting through Live CD and also GParted-Boot-Correction CD.  When logged-in through Live CD, I ran 'lsblk' and it showed two physical hard disks. As I mentioned above, I had removed the 3rd hard disk. GParted-Boot-Correction CD was not able to show dialog box and it was doing some cpu activity. It showed random lines on the screen as if the display is bad.

Comment: I haven't used **GParted-Boot-Correction** but **boot-repair** has worked fine for me. You might want to try it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix:  Ignore my previous response. I ran boot-repair from inside Live-CD login. Here is output https://paste.ubuntu.com/26248806/ That did not help. I also selected shim.efi in BIOS.  When I chose shim.efi, it again bought me to Grub screen for OS selection. Then purple screen goes on for ever

Comment: Solved. I removed the root-harddisk and connected it to another machine. Opened /etc/fstab file and commented out following line. Then connected the hard drive back to original machine. OS booted. This implies if the EXTERNAL drive is not unmounted gracefully, then the OS does not boot next time. That seems unusual. I would like some one confirm that thanks. "#windows ext drive
#UUID=9A8C91E08C91B76B  /media/extsun  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0"